# Is it possible to store a chunk of JS in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I realize this might go into the "worst practices" column but as an experiment I'm trying to refactor a function to the smallest length possible.

The following two lines work great.

```js
let prefix = document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0];
prefix.style.position = "absolute";
```

But when I tried to include code with the target it imploded.

```js
let prefix = 'document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0].style.position';
[prefix] = "absolute";
```

Is something like that even possible or have I crossed the line into a no-go zone?  Thanks so much for any shove in the right direction!

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0]` could be replaced by `document.querySelector(".box")`.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more as I'm not quite sure whate you're asking.

Comment: You're right, in this example that could work.  But the real function I'm using this on has multiple targets and needs `querySelectorAll`.  But thanks though!

Comment: ibrahim what I'm asking is can I place code in a variable or is that strictly forbidden in JS?

Comment: @DR01D You could stick the code in a string and `eval` it, but that's so awful, you shouldn't do it. I think you need to give a better description of your end goal, not this specific issue. This smells very strongly of an XY Problem.

Comment: To "stick code in a variable", I'd wrap in in an anonymous function, but I'm not sure if that'll help what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm not necessarily doing it for any particular reason.  Just trying to push JS until it breaks.  I thought I could use bracket notation `[ ] ` instead of `eval`.  But evidently not because it isn't working.

Comment: @DR01D You can use functions for that sort of things: `function pos(value) { document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0].style.position = value; }`. Then you can call it as much as you want: `pos("absolute");` or `pos("relative");`.

Comment: @DR01D *"Just trying to push JS until it breaks."* - that's easy... `throw new Error("Broke it")`

Comment: For an anonymous function I'd write `f = (v) => document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0].style.position = v; f("absolute");`.

Comment: I think `[]` are eval only in Excel VBA, so maybe that's where the confusion comes from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel. That would be much shorter with CSS, but in certain cases `elementID.style.position = "absolute"` can be used instead of `document.querySelector("#elementID").style.position = "absolute"`

Comment: @Carcigenicate clever with an arrow function!  Ok I'm just glad to see I've pushed this about as far as it can go.  And that's that.  Thanks so much!

Comment: The smallest length possible? change `document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0]` to `document.querySelector(".box")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return the code from a function handle as follow;

```
var prefix=function(position){
    document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0].style.position=position;
};
```

you can use it like this;

```
prefix("absolute");
```

Comment: While I suggested an anonymous function in the comments, really, this is the way to go; unless you only need the function locally, or you're golfing. The size difference shouldn't matter.